# Save data from GET request as variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, get, axios

I've got a simple axios GET request that is working with Azure directline 3.0. The GET request pulls back data and shows it in the console (as seen in the picture).
The data I want to save into a variable is the conversationId. I then want to use this variable with Axios Post in another JS file to post as part of the link e.g. `let URL = "https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/"+convID"/activities"`. With `convID` being the variable I wish to create. Right now I am manually changing the convID with the new conversation ID, but I want to create a variable so I can place it in the post javascript file so it is automatic.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5EaH.png)

Comment: Yeah but I am not sure on how to do it, that is what I am asking

Comment: What happens if a post back occurs or some other kind of navigation that causes your scipt files to reload, this approach won't work, but if you store this value in the browser session storage container, you can pull it from there (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways you can solve this problem. Easiest one being, exposing the data on a shared object `window.convID = convID` and then accessing it wherever required.
You could also look to make `singleton` objects, which can be instantiated only once and hence will share it's variables across the lifespan of the application.

```
axios.get(/* URL */).then(res => {
  window.convID = res.data.conversationId;
});
```

Comment: Okay but how do I get the conversation ID from the GET request and save it?

Comment: How would I be able to call this in another javascript file? I tried using 'alert (convID.back);' but it won't pick it up in the POST file?

Comment: In the `post` file, you can get it by using `window.convID`

Answer (score 0):

You can save that variable value in LocalStorage. Something like this:

```
let routeToYourApi = '/api/conversations'; // or something like this...
axios.get(routeToYourApi).then((response) => {
    let conversationId = response.data.conversationId; // not sure if data object from your image is directly nested inside response that you get from server, but you get the idea...
    window.localStorage.setItem("convId", conversationId);
}) // here you can fetch your conversation id
```

Than you can access it anywhere in your app:

```
let conversationId = window.localStorage.getItem("convId");
```

... and eventually remove it from local storage:

```
window.localStorage.removeItem("convId")
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: How can i fetch the conversation ID from the javascript console to put place it there?